# Parse XML in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I know that there are already numerous topics about querying xml in MS T-SQL, however with all the samples, I wasn't able to get my query to work properly.

I have the following XML:

```
<group>
    <items>
        <groupitem>
            <key>23137</key>
        </groupitem>
        <groupitem>
            <key>23139</key>
        </groupitem>
        <groupitem>
            <key>23151</key>
        </groupitem>
        <groupitem>
            <key>23153</key>
        </groupitem>
    </items>
</group>
```

I want to get all the 'key' items, so that I can insert them into a table (so 4 rows)

I started off putting my xml into variable @xml and running this query:

```
SELECT doc.value('(key/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') AS 'key'
    FROM @xml.nodes('/group/items/groupitem/*') AS ref(doc)
```

That gave me 4 empty rows, and if I remove the [1], it gives me this error: "XQuery [value()]: '*value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'*"

Then I tried this:

```
SELECT doc.value('(/group/items/groupitem/key)[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') AS 'key'
    FROM @xml.nodes('/group/items/groupitem/*') AS ref(doc)
```

That actually gave me some data, but unfortunately, it's 4 times the same key 23137, probably caused by the [1] in the statement. Removing it however    brings me back to the same error message as before.

I know how I should do it in Xpath (/group/items/groupitem/key), but can't get my head around how I should do it in T-Sql. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any reason to put an asterisk at the end of your XPath expression in `.nodes()`? Are you expecting different Elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    doc.value('(key)[1]', 'int') AS 'key'
FROM 
    @xml.nodes('/group/items/groupitem') AS ref(doc)
```

In my case, this returns an output like:

```
key
-----
23137
23139
23151
23153
```

Is that what you're looking for?

The call to `.nodes()` basically gives you a "pseudo" table of XML fragments - one for each match of the XPath expression. So in your case, you get four rows of XML back, each representing the contents of the `<groupitem>` node. You reach into that, grab the value of the `<key>` element contained inside, cast it to an `int` - and presto, you're done!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that was indeed what I was looking for. One more question: why is the [1] needed?

Comment: @ErikL: because potentially, there could be multiple elements nested under a parent element. Just using `(key)` would return a **collection** of elements, and you cannot convert an entire collection of XML elements into an atomic value (like an `int`) - only a single element

Answer (score 2):

In the following query, context element of `doc` is already `key` element :

```
SELECT doc.value('(key/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') AS 'key'
FROM @xml.nodes('/group/items/groupitem/*') AS ref(doc)
```

So you should not mention `key` again in the select clause. You can use `.` instead to reference current context element :

```
SELECT doc.value('.', 'nvarchar(255)') AS 'key'
FROM @xml.nodes('/group/items/groupitem/*') AS ref(doc)
```

Comment: Thanks, that does indeed work. I'm guessing that the * in the nodes statement works as a wildcard, and that since there's only one element below groupitem, that gets assigned to the root of doc?

Comment: It may be text() was on purpose in OP's query, ignoring deeper nodes content probably. Then '(./text())[1]'